# Разделение строки на равные куски (конкретное число кусков)

Tags: php, lua

Я пользовался [этим ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527048/split-string-in-equal-chunks-in-lua) на точно такой же вопрос, однако у меня возникли проблемы. Мне нужен один и тот же функционал, но на 2 языках. На php код выглядит так:

```
 $chunks = str_split($text, strlen($text)/16);
```

Здесь количество частей получается 15. В то же время, пользуясь кодом из вышеупомянутого вопроса в Lua, я получаю 14 частей, следовательно разбиение одной и той же строки различается. В качестве строки выступают данные, считанные из файла obj (длина строки большая, поэтому посимвольный подсчёт не годится)

Подскажите пожалуйста, как поступить в такой ситуации. Буду рад любой помощи

Единственное, что могу добавить к этому - количество кусков, на которые нужно разделить - чётное

Comment: А в итоге какие данные содержатся и там и там?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Латиница и кирилица(с ней сложнее, меняется для этого кодировка)

```
$text='0123456789abzxcvtynetqw';
$text=iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8', $text);

$res=mb_strlen($text, 'utf-8');

$chast='6';

$del=$res/$chast;
echo 'Части '.$chast.'<br>';
echo 'Кол. символов в строке '.$res.'<br>';
$max=round($del);
echo 'Кол. символов в части '.$max.'<br>';

$text2=chunk_split($text, $max);

$fi=explode(PHP_EOL, $text2);
print_r($fi);

$text1='абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхц';
$text1=iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8', $text1);

$res1=mb_strlen($text1, 'CP1251');

$chast1='6';

$del1=$res1/$chast1;
echo '<br>'.'Части '.$chast1.'<br>';
echo 'Кол. символов в строке '.$res1.'<br>'; //(врёт увеличивает=))
$max1=round($del1);
echo 'Кол. символов в части '.$max1.'<br>'; 

$text2=chunk_split($text1, $max1);

$fi1=explode(PHP_EOL, $text2);
print_r($fi1); // а части делает как надо
```

Comment: спасибо, проблема была в разных кодировках

Comment: @J.Vencedor на кириллицу 2 байта походу)

Comment: так и есть. Из-за этого и хвост различался